# Iterate through an array

Tags: php, jquery, arrays

This is my JQuery code:

```
$.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: 'query2.php',
            data: key,
            dataType: 'json',
            success: function (msg) {

                var cnt = 0;
                $.each(msg, function(){
                    $('#jobtitle').html("<div>" + msg[cnt].jobTitle + "</div>");
                    $('#jobname').html(msg[cnt].jobName);
                    $('#fullname').html(msg[cnt].fullName);
                    $('#phone').html(msg[cnt].phone);
                    $('#mail').html(msg[cnt].mail);
                    $('#city').html(msg[cnt].city);
                    $('#description').html(msg[cnt].description);
                    cnt++;
                });
```

And from my query2.php i get something like this:

```
{'JobTitle': 'a', 'jobName': 'b', ...}, {'JobTitle': 'a', 'jobName': 'c', ...}
```

### Why can't i print the two rows of result? It just print one row.

Update:
First of all, Thanks for all your answers :)

As #Suren Srapyan said, i Used Key, Value + append but the result isn't good. It returns several repetitive value like:

```
شرکتشرکتشرکتشرکتشرکتشرکتشرکتشرکتشرکتشرکتشرکتشرکتشرکتشرکت
گلخانهمهندسیگلخانهمهندسیگلخانهگلخانهمهندسیگلخانهگلخانهمهندسیمهندسیگلخانهمهندسیمهندسی
علی علویمصطفی کلانترعلی علویمصطفی کلانترعلی علویعلی علویمصطفی کلانترعلی علویعلی علویمصطفی کلانترمصطفی کلانترعلی علویمصطفی کلانترمصطفی کلانتر
12345609153040406123456091530404061234561234560915304040612345612345609153040406091530404061234560915304040609153040406
a@a.comM.Mastersoft@gmail.coma@a.comM.Mastersoft@gmail.coma@a.coma@a.comM.Mastersoft@gmail.coma@a.coma@a.comM.Mastersoft@gmail.comM.Mastersoft@gmail.coma@a.comM.Mastersoft@gmail.comM.Mastersoft@gmail.com
مشهدتهرانمشهدتهرانمشهدمشهدتهرانمشهدمشهدتهرانتهرانمشهدتهرانتهران
توضیحات علی علویتوضیحات مصطفیتوضیحات علی علویتوضیحات مصطفیتوضیحات علی علویتوضیحات علی علویتوضیحات مصطفیتوضیحات علی علویتوضیحات علی علویتوضیحات مصطفیتوضیحات مصطفیتوضیحات علی علویتوضیحات مصطفیتوضیحات مصطفی
```

I only have two element of array:

```
{'JobTitle': 'a', 'jobName': 'b', ...}, {'JobTitle': 'a', 'jobName': 'c', ...}
```

Which in my response (browser's Inspect Elements) is right.
And as @memo asked, My HTML is:

```
<div class="row" id="show">
            <div class="cell" id="jobtitle"></div>
            <div class="cell" id="jobname"></div>
            <div class="cell" id="fullname"></div>
            <div class="cell" id="phone"></div>
            <div class="cell" id="mail"></div>
            <div class="cell" id="city"></div>
            <div class="cell" id="description"></div>
        </div>
```

And yes @Z.Alpha, if i don't use append, It prints the last row.

Comment: remove `[cnt]`  from `msg[cnt]`

Comment: is your array valid?i dont think its valid

Comment: it just print one last row?

Comment: please check how [$.each](https://api.jquery.com/each/) function works. You don't need any count variable.

Comment: please paste your html too. As @SurenSrapyan said you override the previous html. Only the last item of array is printed.

Comment: Updated my question.

Comment: $.each is iterating over all elements in that array.Are your array and request correct?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Beacuse your everytime change the **HTML**.

```
$('#jobtitle').append("<div>" + msg[cnt].jobTitle + "</div>");
```

This code is setting Html to that value,then in next iteration it is replacing that with another code,so you see only the last one.

and 
You can remove your `cnt` variable and write like this

```
$.each( msg, function( key, value ) {

    $('#jobtitle').append("<div>" + value.jobTitle + "</div>");
    $('#jobname').append(value.jobName);
    $('#fullname').append(value.fullName);
    $('#phone').append(value.phone);
    $('#mail').append(value.mail);
    $('#city').append(value.city);
    $('#description').append(value.description);

});
```

where `key` is your index like 0,1,2 and `value` is your current item.
See documentation
http://api.jquery.com/jquery.each/
http://api.jquery.com/html/

Answer (score 0):

See this sample this will help

```js
var data = {
  "id": "0001",
  "type": "donut",
  "name": "Cake",
  "ppu": 0.55
}


$.each(data, function() {
  console.log(data);
  console.log(data.id);
  console.log(data.type);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You shoud have use [`.append()`](http://api.jquery.com/append/) rather than [`.html()`](http://api.jquery.com/html/), as `.html()` will replace the previous value/data and then take the last value as the iteration stop. So at the end, will end up with last value. Use code below :

Data receveied should be like this form :

```
var msg = [{'JobTitle': 'a','jobName': 'b'}, { 'JobTitle': 'a','jobName':'c'}];
```

And **js** should be:

```
$.each(msg, function(i, e){
   // one more things, as you use .each
   // then use its 2 argument `e`, to access the properties
   // otherwise use for loop if you want to use 
   // like msg[cnt]
   $('#jobtitle').append("<div>" + e.jobTitle + "</div>");
   $('#jobname').append(e.jobName);
   // same goes the other
   ........
});
```

Here is [**DEMO**](https://jsfiddle.net/norlihazmeyGhazali/1j1c8k4g/)